# pygame square following mouse cursor

Tags: python, pygame

When I run a pygame program, a white square (about 15px by 15px) follows my cursor around the window. This happens on the most basic pygame program and a few others, too.
My most basic pygame program:

```
import pygame, sys

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(30)
```

Why is this happening? Is it my code, my system, or Pygame?
I am running python 3.7, pygame 1.9.4, and macOS 10.13.6.

EDIT:
After running the same program on Crouton (linux) there is no square.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842142/box-around-cursor-pygame

Comment: So is your problem fixed now or is there still a square

Comment: @Ethan It happens on MacOS but not linux

Comment: hmm so im on windows but you could try calling `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()` also if you plan on doing animation you should add `DISPLAYSURF.fill(color)` after you call the update/flip

Comment: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/447

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `pygame.init()` at the beginning? That might be what is causing the problem. Also you do not have a background, which shouldn't be a problem, but I would try it if nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my PC and it worked fine so I'm not sure what is happening but you could try the following:

1. Enter the command pygame.init() on the second line
2. Replace pygame.display.update() with pygame.display.flip()